# programar app con editores de texto en java

Tags: java, ide, sublimetext

Les escribo porque estoy empezando a programar y tengo dudas sobre el editor de texto. la cuestión esta en que he iniciado con el lenguaje de java y a la hora de crear una app las opciones mas frecuentes suelen ser por ejemplo Android studio, opción que ya probé y que no es realmente lo que deseo, pues por ser un IDE integra múltiples librerías propias y lo alejan de la programación pura en java que deseo para practicar. Por eso mi duda es, ¿se pueden programar aplicaciones solo con editores de texto y plugins quizá?, algo como usar sublime text y con plugins tener lo necesario para hacer un archivo Apk de manera efectiva por ejemplo.
También intente con eclipse pero honestamente tengo dudas sobre la importación de librerías, ya que en sublime text basta con colocar "import java.swing.*;", mientras que en eclipse hay que añadir cada librería por separado dentro de una carpeta del proyecto y se me a complicado mucho.
Que me recomendarían para programar de manera pura, con un lenguaje de programación más que con los comandos del IDE
Por cierto soy usuario mac. Muchísimas gracias por todo

Answer (score 0):

claro que si puedes hacer apps con solo editores de texto, el tema es que los ide te entregan gran parte de las herramientas que usaras a la hora de programar, el tema es para que usaras ese lenguaje,dado que por ejemplo sublime text al ser un editor de codigo puedes hacer muchas cosas pero no todas a no ser que uses "plugins" (no soy usuario de sublime text, sino de neovim y visual studio code) pero porlomenos en estos casos hay suficientes "extras" o "plugins" que te permiten transformar tu codigo en una aplicacion tan perfecta como a quieras, otro tema es que mientras si java funciona para multiples propositos, el hecho de que usaras android studio me dice que tu idea es el crear apps moviles, de ser asi no esta mal empezar por java, pero el mismo es demaciado complejo segun yo como para gentes que recien empieza con el codigo en si, en mi caso yo empece con c# pero principalmente lo que hice fue aprender lo basico, desde variables hasta programacion orientada a objetos y luego pasarme a python (primero por experimentar) y me termine quedando por lo comodo que es para mi, a lo mejor te enfocas mucho en aprender java por lo potente y complejo que es, cuando podrias aprender javascript o incluso kotlin que podria permitirte hacer apps android de forma mas facil y comoda.